# Group Policy installation failed error %%1274

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, deployment

OK, I have a really tough one I've already spent all morning on.

PC is a Win7 64 with SP1 and all MS Patches
Usual error everyone is familiar with:
The assignment of application Adobe Reader X MUI from policy Software Install failed.  The error was : %%1274

Failed to apply changes to software installation settings.  The installation of software deployed through Group Policy for this user has been delayed until the next logon because the changes must be applied before the user logon.  The error was : %%1274

1. gpupdate /force /boot
2. Done: Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon = Enabled
3. Done: Startup policy processing wait time = 30, 120
4. Done: Updated network card drivers
5. Done: Deleted HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Group Policy
6. Done: GPO permissions check: Authenticated Users have Read access
7. Done: Share permissions check: Everyone has Full access
8. Done: Folder permissions check: Authenticated Users have Read and
   Execute permissions
9. Done: File Permissions check: Inherited
10. Done: PSExec -i -s cmd.exe to make sure I have access to the network
    files
11. Done: PSExec -i -s cmd.exe + re-run explorer.exe and manually start
     the MSIs works fine (they install)
12. Done: I've had instances where a network share with a space in it
     didn't work, so I've added a Share name without a space but the
     installer still fails on that package (and all the others).

I've seen this happen with some WiFi cards, but this computer is using Ethernet.

Is there a way of seeing the MSIExec logs to see exactly what transpired?

As an aside, while all the old Group Policy settings have applied, some IE10 settings I added recently are also refusing to apply.

Comment: Are you receiving any event ID 1129, source Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy in your System Event Log?

Comment: @EvanAnderson Yes. Looks to be happening very shortly after boot: The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has succesfully processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then contact your administrator. DNS settings are correct, it should have no difficulty finding Active Directory etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear. It took me the whole day, but I found this Windows 7 SP1 bug:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2459530

DHCP doesn't get an address on first request because the Windows Boot Firewall rejects the DHCP answer before the Windows Firewall has loaded and replaced it, and allows DHCP answers. In the mean time GP fails to process in that gap.

Ended up it is affecting all GP deployment on this domain (small domain).

MS, I want a refund for my time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your receiving event 1129, source Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy in your System Event Log I'm going to recommend a couple of things:

- Presumably you have other computers that this is working fine on, so I doubt it's an across-the-board problem with Ethernet switch configuration. If your switch is expecting to use spanning tree on the port where this problematic computer is connected, however, the port transitioning through the Listening and Learning states may be the culprit.
- I continue to see problematic NIC drivers, from time to time, that benefit from [disabling DHCP media sense](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239924) when these events are getting logged.
- I have one Customer using a non-Microsoft DHCP relay agent [tickling this bug in Windows 7 to this day](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2459530).

Those items would all be good places to look next.